# Getting all combinations of a string with subscript and specif format

Tags: python, combinations, pymatgen

I have seen various combination formats. But I have to try something new.
Lets say, we have three lists:

```
A = ('Li', 'B', 'C', 'N')
B = ('Li', 'B', 'C', 'N')  
X = ('O', 'Br', 'Cl')
```

All the element of `A` are same as `B`. Now I need to create all possible combinations in the following formats:

```
# (i)   ABX3
# (ii)  AA'B2X6
# (iii) A2B2X6
```

Where A2 (is A_{2}) is 'A' with 2 in subscript and A!=A' in the combination.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import itertools
elem_list = ['Li','B','C','N']
CCA_combos1 = list(itertools.combinations(elem_list, 2)) 
display(CCA_combos1, len(CCA_combos1))
   
listX1 = ('O','Cl', 'Br')
CCA_combosX = []
for x in range(len(CCA_combos1)):
  for y in range(0,len(listX1)):
    CCA_combosX += [tuple(CCA_combos1[x]) + tuple(listX1[y])]

resX1 = [''.join(tups) for tups in CCA_combosX]
```

The above code not working well for `Br` and `Cl`
I have no idea yet to create combination in `A2BB'X6`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `A!=A' in the combination.`?

Comment: `"Where A2 (is A_{2}) is 'A' with 2 in subscript and A!=A' in the combination"`  hard to understand. Can you explain that a more in detail ?

Comment: I don't want to speak for OP but `A != A'` looks like it means they are distinct elements.

Comment: If I'd have to guess I'd say, `A2` means "take element of group A twice ('C2' or 'N2')" while `AA'` means "pick two elements of group A but the one can not be equal to the other"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `itertools.product`. I hope I understood your question correctly.

```py
from itertools import product

A = ('Li', 'B', 'C', 'N')
B = ('Li', 'B', 'C', 'N')
X = ('O', 'Br', 'Cl')

list1, list2, list3 = [], [], []

# (i)   ABX3
for a, b, x in product(A, B, X):
    print(a, b, x, 3)
    list1.append((a, b, x, 3))

# (ii)  AA'B2X6
for a, ap, b, x in product(A, A, B, X):
    if a != ap:
        print(a, ap, b, 2, x, 6)
        list2.append((a, ap, b, 2, x, 6))

# (iii) A2B2X6
for a, b, x in product(A, B, X):
    print(a, 2, b, 2, x, 6)
    list3.append((a, 2, b, 2, x, 6))
    
    
# print the number of elements in each list
print('\n(i)   ABX3:', len(list1))
print('(ii)  AA\'B2X6:', len(list2))
print('(iii) A2B2X6:', len(list3))
```

Outputs:

```
# (i)
Li Li O 3
Li Li Br 3
Li Li Cl 3
Li B O 3
Li B Br 3
Li B Cl 3
Li C O 3
Li C Br 3
Li C Cl 3
Li N O 3
Li N Br 3
Li N Cl 3
B Li O 3
B Li Br 3
B Li Cl 3
B B O 3
B B Br 3
B B Cl 3
B C O 3
B C Br 3
B C Cl 3
B N O 3
B N Br 3
B N Cl 3
C Li O 3
C Li Br 3
C Li Cl 3
C B O 3
C B Br 3
C B Cl 3
C C O 3
C C Br 3
C C Cl 3
C N O 3
C N Br 3
C N Cl 3
N Li O 3
N Li Br 3
N Li Cl 3
N B O 3
N B Br 3
N B Cl 3
N C O 3
N C Br 3
N C Cl 3
N N O 3
N N Br 3
N N Cl 3
```

```
# (ii)
Li B Li 2 O 6
Li B Li 2 Br 6
Li B Li 2 Cl 6
Li B B 2 O 6
Li B B 2 Br 6
Li B B 2 Cl 6
Li B C 2 O 6
Li B C 2 Br 6
Li B C 2 Cl 6
Li B N 2 O 6
Li B N 2 Br 6
Li B N 2 Cl 6
Li C Li 2 O 6
Li C Li 2 Br 6
Li C Li 2 Cl 6
Li C B 2 O 6
Li C B 2 Br 6
Li C B 2 Cl 6
Li C C 2 O 6
Li C C 2 Br 6
Li C C 2 Cl 6
Li C N 2 O 6
Li C N 2 Br 6
Li C N 2 Cl 6
Li N Li 2 O 6
Li N Li 2 Br 6
Li N Li 2 Cl 6
Li N B 2 O 6
Li N B 2 Br 6
Li N B 2 Cl 6
Li N C 2 O 6
Li N C 2 Br 6
Li N C 2 Cl 6
Li N N 2 O 6
Li N N 2 Br 6
Li N N 2 Cl 6
B Li Li 2 O 6
B Li Li 2 Br 6
B Li Li 2 Cl 6
B Li B 2 O 6
B Li B 2 Br 6
B Li B 2 Cl 6
B Li C 2 O 6
B Li C 2 Br 6
B Li C 2 Cl 6
B Li N 2 O 6
B Li N 2 Br 6
B Li N 2 Cl 6
B C Li 2 O 6
B C Li 2 Br 6
B C Li 2 Cl 6
B C B 2 O 6
B C B 2 Br 6
B C B 2 Cl 6
B C C 2 O 6
B C C 2 Br 6
B C C 2 Cl 6
B C N 2 O 6
B C N 2 Br 6
B C N 2 Cl 6
B N Li 2 O 6
B N Li 2 Br 6
B N Li 2 Cl 6
B N B 2 O 6
B N B 2 Br 6
B N B 2 Cl 6
B N C 2 O 6
B N C 2 Br 6
B N C 2 Cl 6
B N N 2 O 6
B N N 2 Br 6
B N N 2 Cl 6
C Li Li 2 O 6
C Li Li 2 Br 6
C Li Li 2 Cl 6
C Li B 2 O 6
C Li B 2 Br 6
C Li B 2 Cl 6
C Li C 2 O 6
C Li C 2 Br 6
C Li C 2 Cl 6
C Li N 2 O 6
C Li N 2 Br 6
C Li N 2 Cl 6
C B Li 2 O 6
C B Li 2 Br 6
C B Li 2 Cl 6
C B B 2 O 6
C B B 2 Br 6
C B B 2 Cl 6
C B C 2 O 6
C B C 2 Br 6
C B C 2 Cl 6
C B N 2 O 6
C B N 2 Br 6
C B N 2 Cl 6
C N Li 2 O 6
C N Li 2 Br 6
C N Li 2 Cl 6
C N B 2 O 6
C N B 2 Br 6
C N B 2 Cl 6
C N C 2 O 6
C N C 2 Br 6
C N C 2 Cl 6
C N N 2 O 6
C N N 2 Br 6
C N N 2 Cl 6
N Li Li 2 O 6
N Li Li 2 Br 6
N Li Li 2 Cl 6
N Li B 2 O 6
N Li B 2 Br 6
N Li B 2 Cl 6
N Li C 2 O 6
N Li C 2 Br 6
N Li C 2 Cl 6
N Li N 2 O 6
N Li N 2 Br 6
N Li N 2 Cl 6
N B Li 2 O 6
N B Li 2 Br 6
N B Li 2 Cl 6
N B B 2 O 6
N B B 2 Br 6
N B B 2 Cl 6
N B C 2 O 6
N B C 2 Br 6
N B C 2 Cl 6
N B N 2 O 6
N B N 2 Br 6
N B N 2 Cl 6
N C Li 2 O 6
N C Li 2 Br 6
N C Li 2 Cl 6
N C B 2 O 6
N C B 2 Br 6
N C B 2 Cl 6
N C C 2 O 6
N C C 2 Br 6
N C C 2 Cl 6
N C N 2 O 6
N C N 2 Br 6
N C N 2 Cl 6
```

```
# (iii)
Li 2 Li 2 O 6
Li 2 Li 2 Br 6
Li 2 Li 2 Cl 6
Li 2 B 2 O 6
Li 2 B 2 Br 6
Li 2 B 2 Cl 6
Li 2 C 2 O 6
Li 2 C 2 Br 6
Li 2 C 2 Cl 6
Li 2 N 2 O 6
Li 2 N 2 Br 6
Li 2 N 2 Cl 6
B 2 Li 2 O 6
B 2 Li 2 Br 6
B 2 Li 2 Cl 6
B 2 B 2 O 6
B 2 B 2 Br 6
B 2 B 2 Cl 6
B 2 C 2 O 6
B 2 C 2 Br 6
B 2 C 2 Cl 6
B 2 N 2 O 6
B 2 N 2 Br 6
B 2 N 2 Cl 6
C 2 Li 2 O 6
C 2 Li 2 Br 6
C 2 Li 2 Cl 6
C 2 B 2 O 6
C 2 B 2 Br 6
C 2 B 2 Cl 6
C 2 C 2 O 6
C 2 C 2 Br 6
C 2 C 2 Cl 6
C 2 N 2 O 6
C 2 N 2 Br 6
C 2 N 2 Cl 6
N 2 Li 2 O 6
N 2 Li 2 Br 6
N 2 Li 2 Cl 6
N 2 B 2 O 6
N 2 B 2 Br 6
N 2 B 2 Cl 6
N 2 C 2 O 6
N 2 C 2 Br 6
N 2 C 2 Cl 6
N 2 N 2 O 6
N 2 N 2 Br 6
N 2 N 2 Cl 6
```

```
(i)   ABX3: 48
(ii)  AA'B2X6: 144
(iii) A2B2X6: 48
```

Comment: How do I store 1. print(a, b, x, 3), 2.  print(a, ap, b, 2, x, 6) and 3.  print(a, 2, b, 2, x, 6) in different variables. So that we can operate them in future. For example I want to merge the combinations (1 and 2) or (1 and 3).

Comment: same time I want to count the number of combination in each.

Comment: You can simply use lists. I edited the answer to store the variables into 3 different lists.

Comment: There is huge redundancy in the output. For example ABO3 is similar to BAO3.   I am just pointing on one example of output list i.e. LiBO3 and BLiO3 are same